# Select inside select (SQL to lambda linq expression)

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, lambda

```
Select Label,
(SELECT COUNT(*) from [CourtSessions] cs where cs.iDCity = Cit.ID) as courts, 
(Select COUNT(*) from [Cases] c inner join [CourtSessions] cs ON c.ID = cs.iDCase where cs.iDCity = Cit.ID) as csnatures 
FROM Cities Cit
Group by Label, id
```

I tried this but it doesn't work

```
var data = db.Cities
      .GroupBy(a => a.label)
      .Select(g => new
      {
          city = g.Key,
          sessions = db.CourtSessions.Include(p => p.CityTB).Count(o => o.CityTB.label == g.Key),
          cases = db.Cases.Join(db.CourtSessions, u => u.ID, ui => ui.iDCase, (u, ui) => new { u, ui }).Count(m => m.ui.CityTB.label == g.Key)

      });
```

Where CityTB is a foreign key

Cases (ID ...)
Cities (ID, Label)
CourtSession (ID, iDCase, iDCity ... CasesTB, CityTB)

I am getting this exception

> base {System.Exception} = {"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[LawbookMVC.Models.CourtSession] Include[CourtSession,City](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[LawbookMVC.Models.CourtSession], System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[LawbookMVC.Mod...

Thanks.

Comment: Are you getting any exception? If yes specify it in your question.

Comment: yes i just included it

Comment: You probably want `select` instead of `Include`

Answer (score 0):

Well i solved it, thanks you all

```
var dat = db.Cities
          .GroupBy(a => new { a.label, a.ID})
          .Select(g => new
          {
              city = g.Key.label,
              sessions = db.CourtSessions.Count(o => o.iDCity == g.Key.ID),//,
              cases = db.Cases.Join(db.CourtSessions, u => u.ID, ui => ui.iDCase, (u, ui) => new { u, ui }).Count(m => m.ui.CityTB.label == g.Key.label)

          });
```